# How to find the value of $\cos36^\circ$ using the properties of a regular pentagon?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Using the properties of a regular pentagon, how can I show the following? $$\cos36^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}$$

How can I use the sine law or the cosine law?

I can show the result using $\cos(2\theta)=\cos(3\theta)$, but how can I use the properties of a regular pentagon?

Comment: Can you find an angle of $36^\circ$ somewhere in the pentagon? Because without an angle of $36^\circ$ somewhere, you can't get started.

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ABCDE$ is a regular pentagon, then $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ACD$ are both isosceles triangles with the angle at $A$ equal to $36^\circ$. If we let $s$ be the side length of the pentagon, and $t$ be the length of the diagonal of the pentagon, then the law of cosines on these two triangles gives
$$
s^2 = s^2+t^2-2st\cos 36^\circ\\
s^2 = t^2+t^2-2t^2\cos 36^\circ
$$
Simplifying the first equation (and assuming $t \neq 0$) gives
$$
t = 2s\cos 36^\circ
$$
Inserting this into the second equation (and assuming that $s\neq 0$) gives
$$
s^2 = 8s^2\cos^236^\circ - 8s^2\cos^236^\circ\\
1 = 8\cos^236^\circ - 8\cos^336^\circ
$$
Letting $x = 2\cos36^\circ$, we can rewrite this as
$$
1 = 2x^2-x^3\\
x^3-2x^2+1 = 0
$$
It's not difficult to see that $1$ is a solution (the rational root theorem tells us that $\pm 1$ are the only possible rational solutions, so checking them is a reasonable thing to do). But we know that $\cos36^\circ \neq \frac12$. (That's $\cos 60^\circ$, the only other case where two isosceles triangles with side lengths $a, a, b$ and $a, b, b$ have an angle in common: $a = b$. This is also a way to spot that $x = 1$ is a solution to the cubic equation.) So we factor out that solution, and what remains is
$$
x^2-x-1 = 0
$$
which has one positive solution: $x = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.